# Builder can not write without either data or a file path or a symlink path: os/packages/packages.json

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

When I run meteor 1.6, it throw an error--
**Builder can not write without either data or a file path or a symlink path: os/packages/packages.json**

Comment: On a new project or an existing one? If second, can you briefly describe the project structure?